# Terminology : Hahn-Jordan decomposition

Tags: measure-theory

Here is what I could find in most analysis textbooks :

Let $\mu$ be a signed measure on a measure space $(X, \mathcal{A})$.

- A Hahn decomposition is any pair $(P,N)$ of measurable sets such that $P \cup N = X$ and $P \cap N = \emptyset$ such that $\mu(A) \geq 0$ for all $A \subseteq P$ and $\mu(B) \leq 0$ for all $B \subseteq N$;
- The Jordan decomposition are the unique positives measure $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$ such that $\mu = \mu^+ - \mu^-$ and such that $\mu^+ \perp \mu^-$;

I overheard people talking about the Hahn-Jordan decomposition but the precise definition of this eludes me. I couldn't find any such thing in Folland's Real Analysis or in Rudin's Real and complex analysis.

Does such a thing exists or is it just a shortcut for 'Hahn decomposition of $X$ w/r to $\mu$ and Jordan decomposition of $\mu$' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mention above, the Jordan decomposition of $\mu$ into $\mu^+$ and $\mu^{-}$ has a (possibly non-unique) Hahn decomposition 'lurking in the background'.

So I would interpret 'the Hahn-Jordan decomposition' as being synonymous with 'the Jordan decomposition' of $\mu$, i.e.

*''the Hahn-Jordan decomposition of $\mu$''* $=$ *''the Jordan decomposition of $\mu$''*.

Comment: Can I think that the Hahn Decomposition is the decomposition of $X$ while Jordan decomposition is the decomposition of $\mu$?